# Cannot get the 3D Audio effect for skAudioNode in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, ios9

I am trying out the new skAudioNode which is announced in WWDC 2015. I am new to swift and spriteKit.

First in sks editor I drag an Audio object into scene and give a name as audioNodeRed which attached to a visually red sprikit node. I specify a wav file link to this node in the editor.

In GameScene.swift, I wrote:

```
let redNode:SKAudioNode = childNodeWithName("//audioNodeRed") as! SKAudioNode;
let actionPlaySound = SKAction.play()
redNode.runAction(actionPlaySound)
```

The last line will crash with an error : terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'required condition is false: _engine->IsRunning()'

I fixed it by specified a wav file to action by code (xcode bug?)

```
let actionPlaySound =SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Crackling_Fireplace.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
```

Ok now I can hear the sound but there's no 3d audio effect if I move the node, I have already specify the listener position of the scene(still in GameScene.swift):

```
//sprite is a skSpriteNode in the center of the screen
self.listener = sprite
```

Another thing is I can not access the avaudioengine properties as specified in the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAudioNode/). e.g.

```
  redAudioNode.avAudioNode //SKAudioNode does not have a member named "avAudioNode"
  myScene.audioEngine   //SKScene does not have a member named "audioEngine"
```

I am using XCode 7 beta version4. I want to know if I am doing something wrong here or the reason is the ios9 framework is still in beta. Thanks for the help.

-------------add----------------

OK, I got the 3d audio effect by going to the background and going back to the app again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figure out the problem myself, apparently there is something wrong with the sks editor.

if I do it in code in stead of in the editor, I hear the 3D sound effect.

```
 audioNodeRed.positional = true
 audioNodeRed.autoplayLooped = true
```